# Sliding winddow and threshold value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table with temperature and  timestamp:

```
20  2017-09-08 06:20:27.1600000
22  2017-09-08 06:17:57.1566667
19  2017-09-08 06:28:57.1900000
19  2017-09-08 06:25:27.1900000
19  2017-09-08 06:21:27.1633333
19  2017-09-08 06:23:27.1800000
19  2017-09-08 06:25:57.1866667
19  2017-09-08 06:27:27.1866667
16  2017-09-08 06:35:27.2066667
18  2017-09-08 06:23:57.1800000
....
```

I'm trying to calculate if is above a certain level, in a given period. Say 18 degrees in 4 minutes.

I been Googleing around bud didn't came up with any useful.  I could of course just bruteforce it with a while loop, but is there a smarter way of doing it?

SQL Server 2017: So no language limitations :)

Comment: I have an idea, but i dont know if it will work across multiple values on the same day, maybe it needs some tweaking. But Cross apply your value when degree hits 18, and substract your timestamp, and see if its withing 4 minutes and degree is above 17. But you need some kind of split when it hits back to 18 from ex 19.

Comment: @plaidDK I would like to see your solution

Comment: Sorry I dont think i quitely understood your question. Why do you want the value 16 degrees? I cant see the logic, but maybe im misunderstanding something? Dont you want the values where its 18 degrees or more within 4 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `exists`, but this will not have good performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.temperature >= 18 and
                        t2.timestamp >= t.timestamp and
                        t2.timestamp < dateadd(minute, 4, t.timestamp)
                 );
```